Bootstrap 5.3 - fixed-top navbar versus dark theme
I cannot find a way to have a fixed top navigation bar that isn't transparent with both dark and light themes.
When toggling to dark (or light), the fixed-top is visibly transparent, content flows visibly underneath.
Before adding the dark theme I had a bg-light and fixed-top which together delivered a perfect result, but bg-light is incompatible with the dark theme, the navbar stays light.
I sense that I have to write a custom JS function to work around this, but before I do, would anyone have a native Bootstrap solution for that ?
Thanks

Looks the code was skipped :
< nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg border-bottom border-2 mb-3" data-bs-theme="dark" >
Previously this worked well :
< nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light fixed-top border-bottom border-2 mb-3" >

submitted https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/40625

So the solution was using bg-body, an option I wasn't aware of shared by Julien from the Bootstrap team.
< nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body fixed-top border-bottom border-2 mb-3" data-bs-theme="dark" >
